# Type hints for 'Sequence of ParamSpec'

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a working function that looks something like this:

```python
from time import monotonic
from itertools import chain
from datetime import timedelta
from typing import Callable, Sequence, Any, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec('P')


def test_function(
    func: Callable[P, Any],
    args: list[P.args],  # Error: "args" member of ParamSpec is valid only when used with *args parameter
    kwargs: list[P.kwargs]  # Error: "kwargs" member of ParamSpec is valid only when used with **kwargs parameter
) -> None:
    for a, kw in zip(args, kwargs):
        args_str = ', '.join(chain(
            (str(i) for i in a),
            (f"{k}={v}" for k, v in kw.items())
        ))
        start = monotonic()
        func(*a, **kw)
        print(
            f"{func.__name__}({args_str}) "
            f"executed in: {timedelta(seconds=monotonic() - start)}"
        )
```

Some basic usage of this function will look like this:

```py
>>> def f1(a: int, b: float, *, c: int):
...     return a + b + c
...
>>> test_function(f1, [(1, 2), (3, 4)], [{'c': -1}, {'c': -2}])  # essentially no type hints here for args =(
f1(1, 2, c=-1) executed in: 0:00:00.000006
f1(3, 4, c=-2) executed in: 0:00:00.000004
>>>
```

Its only problem for me is the type hints of its `args` and `kwargs` arguments. As you can see, I tried to use [ParamSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec), however, it gave an error (which I indicated in the code comments above) and after reading the documentation, I realized that, unfortunately, I can't just take and do whatever I want with this type:

> They are only valid when used in Concatenate, or as the first argument to Callable, or as parameters for user-defined Generics.

Therefore, my question is: is there any way to still validate a sequence that will contain several groups of arguments, each of which must match the function signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the documentation for [`typing.ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec.args):

> `P.args` [...] should only be used to annotate `*args`. `P.kwargs` [...] should be only be used to annotate `**kwargs`.

So this is not possible to with `ParamSpec`.

The idea of being able to use `P.args`/`P.kwargs` in other scopes is [not new](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1252). But there are fundamental problems that with that, which are unlikely to be solved with `ParamSpec` as is. Actually PEP 612 mentioned the underlying issue briefly, explaining the reason for why `ParamSpec` was introduced in the first place:

> The core problem here is that, by default, parameters in Python can either be called positionally or as a keyword argument. This means we really have three categories (positional-only, positional-or-keyword, keyword-only) we’re trying to jam into two categories. [...] Fundamentally, in order to capture two categories when there are some things that can be in either category, we need a higher level primitive (`ParamSpec`) to capture all three, and then split them out afterward.

A good example was given by [someone in the aforementioned issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1252#issuecomment-1245756829):

```py
def foo(x: int) -> None: ...
def get_callable_and_args(x: Callable[P, Any]) -> Tuple[P.args, P.kwargs]: ...

reveal_type(get_callable_and_args(foo))  # <- What should this reveal?
```

> Should we reveal a tuple of `int` + empty dict? Or should we reveal an empty tuple and a singleton dict that maps `x` to `int`? [...] the existence of "positional-or-keyword" arguments in Python makes things highly ambiguous. [...]
> To fully resolve this kind of issue, there needs to be a way in the type system to represent positional-only, positional-or-keyword, and keyword-only parameters separately. But at that point, it's going to be a different language feature, not `ParamSpec` anymore.

So I would not hold my breath for `ParamSpec` to support this any time soon.

---

If we were talking only about *positional* arguments, what you want there would be possible with the [`TypeVarTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple). [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#type-variable-tuples-with-callable) specifically suggests they can be used as `Callable` arguments.

Something like this should then be possible:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, TypeVarTuple

Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")


def test_function(func: Callable[[*Ts], Any], args: list[tuple[*Ts]]) -> None:
    for a in args:
        func(*a)
```

I say *should* because it is still hard to verify since [`mypy` does not fully support PEP 646 yet](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12280).

But even so, no support for keyword-arguments. Basically, as soon as a *combination* of the three different parameter categories comes up, things get tricky fast.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't reshape `ParamSpec` like that, with some API juggling you can achieve almost the same effect with minimal boilerplate code whilst retaining static typing. The key is to bind `P = ParamSpec("P")` to a class, then use that class's methods (which are bound to `P`) to do the type-checking for you.

First, a demonstration of what the final API could look like. I'm using mypy to generate the errors, but this should be compliant with other type-checkers.

```py
def f1(a: int, b: float, *, c: int) -> float:
    return a + b + c

# Version 1 - sequence of procedural calls
>>> tester = FunctionTester(f1)
>>> tester.add_args(1, 2, c=-1)
>>> tester.add_args(3, 4, c=-2)
>>>
>>> # mypy: Argument 1 to "add_args" of "FunctionTester" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" [arg-type]
>>> # mypy: Argument "b" to "add_args" of "FunctionTester" has incompatible type "List[<nothing>]"; expected "float" [arg-type]
>>> # mypy: Unexpected keyword argument "d" for "add_args" of "FunctionTester" [call-arg]
>>> # tester.add_args("", b=[], d=object())
>>>
>>> tester.test()
f1(1, 2, c=-1) executed in: 0:00:00.000002
f1(3, 4, c=-2) executed in: 0:00:00.000001

# Version 2 - minimalist API using a context manager which automatically calls the test upon exit
>>> with FunctionTester(f1) as test:
...     test(1, 2, c=-1)
...     test(3, 4, c=-2)
...
...     # mypy: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" [arg-type]
...     # mypy: Argument "b" has incompatible type "List[<nothing>]"; expected "float" [arg-type]
...     # mypy: Unexpected keyword argument "d" [call-arg]
...     # test("", b=[], d=object())
f1(1, 2, c=-1) executed in: 0:00:00.000001
f1(3, 4, c=-2) executed in: 0:00:00.000001
```

Now, the implementation:

```py
from types import TracebackType
from typing import (
    Any,
    Callable,
    Generic,
    ParamSpec,
    Sequence,
)
from typing_extensions import Self

from datetime import timedelta
from itertools import chain
from time import monotonic


P = ParamSpec("P")


class FunctionTester(Generic[P]):

    _func: Callable[P, Any]
    _arg_groups: list[tuple[tuple[Any, ...], dict[str, Any]]]

    def __init__(self, function_: Callable[P, Any]) -> None:
        self._func = function_
        self._arg_groups = []

    def add_args(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
        self._arg_groups.append((args, kwargs))

    def test(self) -> None:
        func: Callable[P, Any] = self._func
        for a, kw in self._arg_groups:
            args_str = ", ".join(
                chain(
                    (str(i) for i in a),
                    (f"{k}={v}" for k, v in kw.items()),
                )
            )
            start = monotonic()
            func(*a, **kw)
            print(
                f"{func.__name__}({args_str}) "
                f"executed in: {timedelta(seconds=monotonic() - start)}"
            )
    
    # The following additional methods allow the API in Version 2

    __call__ = add_args

    def __enter__(self) -> Self:
        return self

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type: type[BaseException],
        exc_val: BaseException,
        exc_tb: TracebackType,
    ) -> None:
        self.test()
```